# automatic sharing of post in facebook using login and password

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i build a web application that Generate dynamically an Image (selected Background + quote given by user), at the end of the process of generating the image, i want to disable the "saving Image" option, and **automatically share this image on a Facebook page which is mine** (**not the user's**, i found many example that shows how to create a post on the current facebook account), and than redirect the user to that post on my page so he can share the image from my page ?

is there anyway i can't do that in code behind C# or Java-script (any lead is welcome...)

Answer (score 0):

This will be possible and should be done server side because you'll need a page access token to persist.

First off you'll need to get a page access token and extend it's expiry. This can be done as follows:

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and select your app from the application drop down.
2. Select get token and set the following scopes - publish_actions and manage_pages.
3. Submit me/accounts to get a list of the pages you manage and their page access token
4. Copy the access token you require and extend it using these instructions which will return a long lived access token - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

Now you have the access token that you require for your server side code.

Publishing photos is documented here. The endpoint that you're hitting is dependent on whether or not you want to add the photo to an album
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/photo#publishing

For the server side code you could use this .net sdk http://facebooksdk.net/ which documents uploading files here http://facebooksdk.net/docs/making-synchronous-requests/

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("your saved access token");
string attachementPath = @"C:\\image.jpg";
dynamic result = fb.Post("me/photos",
new
    {
        file = new FacebookMediaObject
                {
                    ContentType = "image/jpeg",
                    FileName = Path.GetFileName(attachementPath)
                }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(attachementPath))
    });
var postId = result.id
```